# Rails 4: Upload image from path given in CSV file

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip, carrierwave

I am exporting products using CSV file in my application. I have an image field where I provide location of image for each products, which can be link or path on local machine.

Can I upload the image from the machine the user is using to access the site? I can successfully do it when I am using links or locations inside server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope. Think about if you were able to do that, from a security perspective. Any website you access would be able to read whatever it wanted from your file system! Thankfully, it's not possible.

In the case of CarrierWave, PaperClip etc where the user CAN upload files to the server: The user themselves picks the file itself within the browser, and when the request is sent to the server, the specific file, that has been explicitly selected from the user, is uploaded as part of the request itself. So, the file is sent to the server - the server never reads from the user's file system per se.

The difference is:

This is OK: "Hey, server, here's a file I've selected, I'm passing it to you so you can process it"

This is NOT OK: "Hey user, I know you've just sent me a request. I'm going to take it upon myself to read what I want from your file system!"

Comment: But how does PaperClip, CarrierWave etc. do that? They are basically getting a file from the user right?

Comment: The user themselves picks the file itself within the browser, and when the request is sent to the server, the specific file, that has been explicitly selected from the user, is uploaded as part of the request itself. So, the file is sent to the server - the server never reads from the user's file system per se.

Comment: So, there is no way a file can be uploaded using a CSV right?

Comment: Nope, CSV is text only.